# Cannot run flows from mule studio in Anypoint studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Installed Anypoint studio configured it to use Mule 3.4, imported my flows and now when I select "run as" to test them I get an error saying I do not have a licence for data mapper even though I do not use the data mapper in the flows that I have imported from mule studio.

Can I disable or remove the data mapper component from Anypoint so I can run my imported flows (which where developed and work in Mule studio)?

Comment: Is there any reference to EE artifacts in `pom.xml`? Or to EE schemas in the Mule XML configs?

Comment: @DavidDossot Correct! Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably still have a reference to EE artifacts in the `pom.xml`. Or to EE schemas in the Mule XML configs. Or both...

Make sure to only refer to CE artifacts and schemes only.